# Codeigniter session issue with multiple frameworks in same folder

Tags: codeigniter, session, frameworks

I have a little problem.

I've codeigniter installed in my folder `/folder/` and another codeigniter installed in another map in the same folder (`/folder/new_codeigniter/`).

When I'm logged in on `/folder/` framework, and reload a page on `/folder/new_codeigniter/`, I'm getting logged out from `/folder/` framework (they both work on the same database).

Anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that  $config['sess_cookie_name'] and $config['sess_table_name'] are different on each application.

Also - use $config['cookie_prefix'] to avoid collision.

Finally you might need to muck around with $config['cookie_domain'] to also fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks alot! sess_cookie_name fixed the problem :-)